Change labels of a ggplot2 chart

I have the hither graph where on the x-axis you can see it says "Semana 1", "Semana 2", and so on; meaning "Week 1", "Week 2", etc.
I'd like them to say exactly
"20-Dic","28-Dic","03-Ene","10-Ene", "21-Ene", "28-Ene", "2-Feb", "10-Feb"

respectively.
The problem is that if I change the names of the entries in the .csv the order in the graph gets shuffled in a lexicographic manner, as in here:

On the other hand I've been trying to change the names with an ad-hoc solution and I haven't been able to do much.
I was hoping to find an elegant solution. I'm not very well versed in R.
Thanks in advance.

You can pass your desired labels in as a character vector to the labels argument of ggplot2::scale_x_discrete() if you are using {ggplot2}.
weeks <- c(1:9)
df <- data.frame(
  week = paste("Semana", weeks),
  value = dnorm(weeks, mean = 5)
)
df
#>       week        value
#> 1 Semana 1 0.0001338302
#> 2 Semana 2 0.0044318484
#> 3 Semana 3 0.0539909665
#> 4 Semana 4 0.2419707245
#> 5 Semana 5 0.3989422804
#> 6 Semana 6 0.2419707245
#> 7 Semana 7 0.0539909665
#> 8 Semana 8 0.0044318484
#> 9 Semana 9 0.0001338302

p <- ggplot2::ggplot(
  data = df,
  ggplot2::aes(x = week, y = value)
) +
  ggplot2::geom_point()
p



p +
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(
    labels = c(
      "20-Dic", "28-Dic", "03-Ene",
      "10-Ene", "21-Ene", "28-Ene",
      "2-Feb", "10-Feb", "20-Oct"
    )
  )


Created on 2024-11-05 with reprex v2.1.1.9000
